# Реакция бота на присоединение нового пользователя в беседу ВК на Python

Tags: python

В интернете к сожалению я не нашёл ответ на мой вопрос, а как реализовать данную задачу - я не представляю! Пишу бота на **Python** для социальной сети **Вконтакте**. Необходимо создать скрипт, благодаря которому бот будет реагировать на присоединение нового пользователя в беседу ВК.

*Под словом "Реагировать" - я имею ввиду отправку любого сообщения.*

Answer (score 0):

В этом видео есть ответ на твой вопрос
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFu8SOHnGLE

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Проверять пишущего пользователя на существование в базе. Если такого нет то выполнить действие которое ты хочешь и записать в базу.

Comment: Это итак понятно. Код интересует.

Comment: Так ясно или не ясно? Ты написал что не представляешь как это реализовать. Я тебе и написал как.
# подключение к бд
# запрос к бд (Покажи все строки в нужной таблице где id = vk_id)
# n = ответ от бд
# if n == ():
# Запрос к бд (запиши в таблицу строку с id = vk_id)
# Нужный скрипт
# отключение от бд